# ASP.NET MVC: Connecting SQL database with Visual Studios for Mac

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio

I am creating my first asp.net web app and have some questions. My project needs to store customer information and their order history (app is like ubereats).

Because my application is not a real website hosted on the internet, every time you close and run the application, you will lose customer accounts from the previous run.

In order to avoid that issue, I thought to use a database. Unfortunately, I have zero experience with databases and how to connect it to the web application on Visual Studios.

I was doing some research on the internet and learned about SQL servers, how can I connect an SQL database with my MVC project on visual studios? Is there a way to host my project locally using a web server?

I am a beginner and would love any recommendations and reading materials! Thank you.

Comment: I recommend utilizing one of the greatest inventions of mankind https://www.google.com to achieve your goals. Best of luck to you bud.

Comment: @jegtugado Easier to ask people w/ experience what the best resources for learning are to narrow down the search. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use SQL Server there are lots of resources out there to help you get started (its fairly easy to get up and running). You can take a look at some of these resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/getting-started/

https://support.mailessentials.gfi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015116400

A quick search will give you a ton of information on getting started with sql server.

As for connecting your app to the database. There are many ways to do this, but for .NET the most common is Entity Framework. Here are some Microsoft resources you can read on getting started with Entity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1

A good starting point would just be to go through these resources and continue to research yourself.

Comment: Awesome, Ill look into it. Thank you